# Are all localizing subcategories reflective when the category has enough injectives?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I've read in [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/localizing+subcategory) the following statement:

"A reflective (strongly) thick subcategory T (of A) is always localizing and the converse holds if A has injective envelopes."

Does anyone know where I can find a proof for the converse? Is it even true? Any book where I can find it?

Comment: I do not quite understand the statement in nlab. Being reflective is part of the definition of a localizing subcategory. So what is meant with "converse". Thickness?

Comment: My definition of "localizing" comes from Gabriel's thesis. A localizing subcategory is a thick subcategory for which the ''quotient functor" has a right adjoint. A reflective subcategory is a subcategory for which the inclusion functor has a left adjoint. Then I don't see why every localizing subcategory is reflective.

Comment: Ah, I confused the localizing T with the localized B.